# How do you prove NO difference in Expected Value, between gambling (probable $−$ EV) vs. investing (probable $+$ EV)?

Tags: uncertainty

##### How do you mathematically prove that "[From a mathematical expected-value standpoint, there is no difference between gambling (e.g. buying a lottery ticket) and investing (e.g. buying a share of stock)](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/63930)" ???

I quote [Vadim Ponomarenko](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/42066/vadim-ponomarenko)'s next sentence, for context.

> The former probably has negative expected value while the latter probably has positive expected value, but that is not a distinction to include in a definition (else every company that gives a bad quarterly earnings report suddenly changes categories).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases, you are buying a lottery, which gives certain amounts of money with certain probabilities.

Assume you have a gamble that gives 50 euro with probability 0.5 and 150 euro with probability 0.5. It costs 100 euro to buy the ticket.

Next, assume you have a stock, priced at 100 euro and the probability that it will rise to 150 is 0.5 while the probability that it will fall to 50 is also 0.5.

In these two cases, the lottery you are facing and its price is the same. If you only care about the probabilities and the outcomes, you should be indifferent between buying the gamble or buying the stock.

Of course, there are other differences. Gambles are usually short horizon lotteries, i.e. you have an initial investment and you have a certain instance after which the gamble ends (and the payoffs are realized). Buying stocks is a more long term problem where (once you bought the stock) the timing of selling (or buying in) it is also important.

Another difference is that a lot of gambles are what we call decision problems under risk (i.e. where the probabilities of the various outcomes are known). Examples are lottery tickets or roulette. Buying stocks is more like a decision problem under uncertainty, where the probabilities that the stock will go up or down is more unknown. (although the distinction between the two is not always that clear cut).